# How to extract all of array value to datagridview in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, datagridview

I have objects stored in the array, the number of objects stored in the array is uncertain. How can I extract all of the array value into `DataGridView`?
here I can only output an array of 10 and will have problems if the number of arrays is less than 10 or more than 10.

```
string[,] rows = new string[,]
{
    {Convert.ToString(no),tb_lokasigambar.Text,  Convert.ToString(nilaipx[newlabel]), Convert.ToString(cekR[newlabel]), Convert.ToString(cekG[newlabel]), Convert.ToString(cekB[newlabel])},
    {Convert.ToString(no),tb_lokasigambar.Text,  Convert.ToString(nilaipx[2]), Convert.ToString(cekR[2]), Convert.ToString(cekG[2]), Convert.ToString(cekB[2])},
    {Convert.ToString(no),tb_lokasigambar.Text,  Convert.ToString(nilaipx[3]), Convert.ToString(cekR[3]), Convert.ToString(cekG[3]), Convert.ToString(cekB[3])},
    {Convert.ToString(no),tb_lokasigambar.Text,  Convert.ToString(nilaipx[4]), Convert.ToString(cekR[4]), Convert.ToString(cekG[4]), Convert.ToString(cekB[4])},
    {Convert.ToString(no),tb_lokasigambar.Text,  Convert.ToString(nilaipx[5]), Convert.ToString(cekR[5]), Convert.ToString(cekG[5]), Convert.ToString(cekB[5])},
    {Convert.ToString(no),tb_lokasigambar.Text,  Convert.ToString(nilaipx[6]), Convert.ToString(cekR[6]), Convert.ToString(cekG[6]), Convert.ToString(cekB[6])},
    {Convert.ToString(no),tb_lokasigambar.Text,  Convert.ToString(nilaipx[7]), Convert.ToString(cekR[7]), Convert.ToString(cekG[7]), Convert.ToString(cekB[7])},
    {Convert.ToString(no),tb_lokasigambar.Text,  Convert.ToString(nilaipx[8]), Convert.ToString(cekR[8]), Convert.ToString(cekG[8]), Convert.ToString(cekB[8])},
    {Convert.ToString(no),tb_lokasigambar.Text,  Convert.ToString(nilaipx[9]), Convert.ToString(cekR[9]), Convert.ToString(cekG[9]), Convert.ToString(cekB[9])},
    {Convert.ToString(no),tb_lokasigambar.Text,  Convert.ToString(nilaipx[10]), Convert.ToString(cekR[10]), Convert.ToString(cekG[10]), Convert.ToString(cekB[10])},

};

int[][] arraybaru = new int[100][];

for (int ii = 0; ii < rows.GetLength(0); ii++)
{
    string[] row = new string[rows.GetLength(1)];
    for (int nn = 0; nn < rows.GetLength(1); nn++)
    {
        row[nn] = rows[ii, nn];
    }
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I see your issue, in a way with your for statements you're treating this parsing as row by column, but in your length measurements your treating it as straight rows and columns. Try something like this:

```
for (int rowID = 0; rowID < rows.Length; rowID++)
{
    string[] newRow = new string[rows[rowID].Length];
    for (int columnID = 0; columnID < rows[rowID].Length; columnID++)
    {
        newRow[columnID] = rows[rowID, columnID];
    }
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

Comment: what the meaning of rowID and columnID?
in this case I want to extract the value from the array [nilaipx] [cekR] [cekG] [cekB]

Comment: @AndiNovanPrastya So with the first for statement, you are simply breaking the array down into its rows, then you get each column with the second for statement by iterating through each value inside the row you just pulled out. Assuming you array is directly compatible with the dataGridView, you could probably just push the row directly into it.